# How do I manage the width of controls through UserControl parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In short, the goal is to propagate LabelWidth to its children in my UserControl class, PropertyView.  See this fragment:

```
     <TabItem.Header>Press</TabItem.Header>
    <TabItem.DataContext>
      <Binding XPath="press_information"/>
    </TabItem.DataContext>
    <W3V:PropertyView LabelWidth="200"></W3V:PropertyView>
```

ANSWER (credit to Athari for his part). To make it work, I needed two elements:  In C#, a dependency property:

```
      public double LabelWidth
      {            get { return (double)this.GetValue(LabelWidthProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(LabelWidthProperty, value); }
      }
      public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelWidthProperty = 
          DependencyProperty.Register(
                   "LabelWidth", typeof(double), typeof(PropertyView), new PropertyMetadata(100.0)
                   );
```

In XAML, the following binding syntax:

```
      <W3V:SimpleControl x:Name="simple"  Content="{Binding}" 
            LabelWidth="{Binding LabelWidth,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=W3V:PropertyView}}" />
```

What didn't work (my original problem):

See the ????? below in the XAML code.  I have NO IDEA what I can put in to make it so the SimpleControl will get a LabelWidth assigned, so that it will set its TextBlock's Width property.

I don't even care what approach is taken, it just needs to deal with the fact that PropertyView is bound to an XML object so it can display its properties, and LabelWidth needs to be a property the control-user sets that gets shoved down into the control.  LabelWidth will vary depending on what object is being displayed, so it can't be global.

```
<UserControl x:Class="W3.Views.PropertyView" ... >

  <UserControl.Resources>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <StackPanel Margin="2" CanVerticallyScroll="true">
    <Border Height="22">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    Text="{Binding XPath=@label}"
             FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Border>
    <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}" Margin="20,0,0,0">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <W3V:SimpleControl x:Name="simple"  
                             Content="{Binding}" 
                             LabelWidth=?????? />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

  </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

C#:

```
public partial class PropertyView : UserControl
{
      public double LabelWidth
      {
        get { return (double)this.GetValue(LabelWidthProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(LabelWidthProperty, value); }
      }
      public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelWidthProperty = 
          DependencyProperty.Register(
                   "LabelWidth2", typeof(double), typeof(PropertyView), new PropertyMetadata(0.0)
                   );
      public PropertyView()
      {
        InitializeComponent();


      }          
}
```

I've searched extensively for a solution that deals with this combination of circumstances, tried many things without success (well, success for simpler situations, but not this), and I'm at a loss here.

Comment: I tried suggest something for u but apparently is was not what u was looking for. Could also copy/paste a short example of structure and content of your XML file?

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you just need to bind `SimpleControl.LabelWidth` to `PropertyView.LabelWidth`? It can be achieved this way:

```
<W3V:SimpleControl
    LabelWidth="{Binding Path=LabelWidth,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=PropertyView}}"
```

P.S. Your dependency property is registered as `"LabelWidth2"` (typo?). And `new PropertyMetadata(0.0)` is redundant, as `default(double) == 0.0`.

Comment: Fails: A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'LabelWidth' property of type 'SimpleControl'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Is `SimpleControl` class yours? `LabelWidth` property should be changed into dependency property. WPF controls are expected to use dependency properties because binding and other features depend on it.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer to edited question**

Here's another go for your problem based on refined question. I'm still not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve but maybe the following points you to right direction, at least.

So there's a Window containing only UserControl. This user control is bound to XML file and it has three label fields. One shows node attritube and the following XML file content. First label's width is bound to property in MainWindow and the other to static converter resource inside the UserControl.

**MainWindow XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:user="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <user:XmlUserControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow Codebehind**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        readonly Random _random = new Random();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public double ControlWidth
        {
            get { return _random.Next(200, 600); }
        }
    }
}
```

**XmlUserControl XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.XmlUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="350">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData" XPath="Data/Items" Source="Items.xml" />
            <local:NodeWidthConverter x:Key="NodeWidthConverter" />
        </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource XmlData}" XPath="*"/>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label x:Name="Title" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                           FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Content="{Binding XPath=@Title}" />
                        <Label Background="BurlyWood" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               Content="{Binding}" Width="{Binding ControlWidth}" />
                        <Label Background="BlanchedAlmond" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Content="{Binding}" Width="{Binding ElementName=Title, Converter={StaticResource NodeWidthConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**XmlUserControl codebehind**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class XmlUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public XmlUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**NodeWidthConverter**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class NodeWidthConverter : IValueConverter 
    {
        public static Random Random = new Random();

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Random.Next(200, 600);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Items.xml sample data**

```
  <Data>
    <Items>
      <Item Title="Title 1">
        <Name>This is item name 1</Name>
        <Summary>Summary for item 1</Summary>
      </Item>
      <Item Title="Title 2">
        <Name>This is item name 2</Name>
        <Summary>Summary for item 2</Summary>
      </Item>
      <Item Title="Title 3">
        <Name>This is item name 3</Name>
        <Summary>Summary for item 3</Summary>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Data>
```

With this you'll get the following. Label has colored background to visualize the changing width properties.

[image: notfound]

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I understand this, it works because the DataContext of UserControl1 is its parent window, MainWindow. But in my case DataContext is {StaticResource aa} which is an XmlDocument. I think I need to override the Binding lookup for this to work for me.

Comment: You need to bind to something that changes. If context is XmlDocument, then it's no-go.

Comment: I still need to set widths somehow. by a different method then?

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Widths of...?

Comment: Widths of the controls generated by my usercontrol.  Ultimately we're dealing with an ItemTemplate to generate many pairs of labels and content, which must be of a parameterized width coming from the main window.

Comment: I'm confused by the use of a Randomized NodeWidthConverter.  Taking out the random and just returning value, what does this even do?

Comment: It's returning a random value :D Point of IValueConverter implementations are to provide one- or twoway conversions between data shown on UI and data actually held on your model. So you can implement your own logic there, say, for control width. One basic use of converters would be a boolean value but instead of that, you want to display "Yes/No" on your UI. And vice versa, if users selects "No", you want to convert it to false. All this via DataBinding.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu ...so you could pass in to the converter the actual XmlNode and create a ruleset for your control width. Should I post a example?

Comment: I'm not seeing the need at this point. The width and the XmlNode are independent items here. I'll keep this in mind for future situations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a failed binding back to your StaticResources? Do you have values defined in the resources section? Try something like this (note that I wrote this directly here (not in VS), it should be pretty much correct :)

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <System.Int x:Key="ContentWidth">100</System.Int> 
    </UserControl.Resources>



    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Width="{StaticResource LabelWidth}" Text="test"/>
        <TextBox Width="{StaticResource ContentWidth}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I would ask if you are really intending to go to StaticResources or whether you meant to bind to a property on a viewmodel or in the code behind of the view?

Comment: I don't have Resources.  I have code-behind properties.  Maybe I should use {Binding} instead of {StaticResource} but I tried that and it fails equally well.  (Maybe also having a datacontext is screwing this up?)  Or should I change my property to bind a UserControl.Resource instead and continue from there?

Comment: @AlanBaljeu You don't want to store these values in StaticResources which is why I questioned it. What is set as the DataContext of your view?

Comment: The DataContext is an XmlDocument that I'm displaying parts of.